# How can I obtain group (factor) level Hessian and gradient from GLMM in lme4?

Tags: lme4-nlme, glmm, gradient, hessian

## Summary

I am working on a problem where I want to determine group level contributions to the maximum likelihood in a GLMM. To do so, I need to access the Hessian and gradients at the group level. This has been done in SAS before, but I am trying to turn this into R code.

General steps:

1. Fit a GLMM on all the data, store the parameter estimates to use as start values in step 2.
2. Fit a GLMM on the data of a single group (i.e. a single subject), setting the number of iterations to 0.
3. From the model in step 2, obtain the Hessian and gradient as [detailed by Ben Bolker](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-mixed-models/2012q2/018094.html)

I have tried various packages (including GLMMadaptive and merDeriv) with little success so far.

### Reproducible example

The work here is based on Fieuws S., Verbeke, G., Boen, F. and Delecluse, C. (2006) "High dimensional multivariate mixed models for binary questionnaire data", Applied Statistics, 55 (4), 449-460.
For the orginal SAS macro and sample data, refer to https://ibiostat.be/onlineresources/uploads/pairwiseMGLMM.zip

#### Preliminaries

```
library(lme4)
library(numDeriv)

df <- read.csv(file = "questiondata.txt", sep = " ")
names(df) <- c("id", "dc", "resp", "physical", "selfesteem", "barriers",  "psychic", "selfperception", "selfeffic", "motivation")
df <- mutate(df,
             id = as.character(id),
             resp = factor(resp,
                           labels = c("negative", "positive"),
                           exclude = ".")
)
```

For the purpose of the example, I will only use a selection of the data. The selection returns a dataset of 2100 observations in 105 subjects

```
d <- filter(df, df["physical"] == 1 | df["selfesteem"] == 1)
```

### Step 1: Fit a model to obtain start values

```
fit <- glmer(resp ~ -1 + physical + selfesteem + physical:dc + selfesteem:dc + (physical + selfesteem | id), 
             data = d,
             family = binomial
             )
initials <- unlist(getME(fit, "theta")) # Store the parameters
```

In the SAS macro this is done as show below:

```
proc nlmixed data=d qpoints=20 noad;
  parms theta_physicial=0 theta_selfesteem=0 alpha1=0 alpha2=0 beta1=0 beta2=0 su1=0 su2=0 su12=0;
  theta=theta_physicial*physical+theta_selfesteem*selfesteem;
  ex=exp(theta+alpha1*physical+alpha2*selfesteem+beta1*dc*physical+beta2*dc*selfesteem);
  p=ex/(1+ex);
  model resp~binary(p);
  random theta_physical theta_selfesteem ~normal([0, 0], [su1*su1, su12, su2*su2]) subject=id;
  estimate 'correl' su12/(su1*su2);
  ods output parameterestimates=params;
run;
```

### Step 2 fit a GLMM on the subject level data

I would like to access the individual's contributions to the MLE so need gradient and Hessian for each subject. In SAS this is done with the BY id argument, providing start values and setting the number of iterations to 0. See the SAS code below:

```
proc nlmixed data=d qpoints=20 noad maxiter=0 start hess;
  parms /data=params;
  theta=theta_physicial*physical+theta_selfesteem*selfesteem;
  ex=exp(theta+alpha1*physical+alpha2*selfesteem+beta1*dc*physical+beta2*dc*selfesteem);
  p=ex/(1+ex);
  model resp~binary(p);
  random theta_physical theta_selfesteem ~normal([0, 0], [su1*su1, su12, su2*su2]) subject=id;
  by id;
  estimate 'correl' su12/(su1*su2);
  ods output hessian=hessian parameterestimates=gradient;
run;
```

I have found a way to extract the Hessian and gradient in lme4 described by Ben Bolder: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-mixed-models/2012q2/018094.html. However if I run the model by subject, it throws an error (which it probably should in most circumstances). Using the `subset` argument does not produce the desired result. It runs the model over 11 groups, not at the individual subject level.
Any ideas on how SAS/STAT PROC NLMIXED gets around this?

```
fit_byid <- glmer(resp ~ -1 + physical + selfesteem + physical:dc + selfesteem:dc + (physical + selfesteem | id), 
             data = filter(d, id == 1),
             family = binomial,
             start = initials,
             control = glmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa", optCtrl = list(maxfun = 0))
)
params <- unlist(getME(fit, c("fixef","theta"))) # Store the parameters
fit_byid_fun <- update(fit_byid, devFunOnly = TRUE) # Access the derivative functions
Hess <- hessian(fit_byid_fun, params) 
gradient <- grad(fit_byid_fun, params)
```

#### Update

I have been able to bypass the errors using the following:

```
fit_byid <- glmer(resp ~ -1 + physical + selfesteem + physical:dc + selfesteem:dc + (physical + selfesteem | id), 
             data = filter(d, id == 1),
             family = binomial,
             start = initials,
             control = glmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa", optCtrl = list(maxfun = 0),
                                    check.nlev.gtr.1 = "ignore", check.rankX = "ignore")
)
```

Unfortunately, this throws another error: `Error in initializePtr() : Downdated VtV is not positive definite`. Working on that now and checking the [GLMM FAQ](http://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#penalizationhandling-complete-separation).

#### Update 2

After some digging, I found out that lme4's optimizer does not return the gradient in a way that I was looking for. I have switched to Rizopoulos' GLMMapdative package which does return the Hessian and the gradient. I was able to retrieve the individual level contributions after a little hacking. I will post the result elsewhere.